# Class representing array Object in java

Tags: java

what would be the name of class representing an array object? eg:

```
int a[] = new int[5]
```

here a is the reference variable.
what is the name of class whoes object's reference id hold in a
System.out.println(a.getClass().getName()) prints [I

is there any rule for naming?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Class name for Array in java**

For Java arrays,the class name is '[' followed by an encoded name of the element class. The number of  '[' character represent the number of dimension of the array

```
Element Type   Encoding

byte              B

boolean           Z

char              C

double            D

float             F

int               I

long              J

short             S

class or interface   Lclassname;
```

**for example :** for float type array class name is   [F

for int [I

for double a[][]=new double[2][3]

class name is [[D

source: http://ohmjavaclasses.blogspot.com/2011/12/class-name-for-array-in-java.html

Answer (score 1):

In general, your class should have a name taken from the problem [domain model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model)'s vocabulary.

Example: If you need to keep an array of books `Book[] books` then a good bet would be to create a `Library` class holding a reference to those books.

To comeback to your question, it depends on what `a` will contain.